Tool/extension for scanning variable references across multiple js files in aspx project
I need to fix the Critical and Blocker issues in the Sonarqube for the aspx project. It contains several (around 500) js files.
Sonar is flagging issues in js files that variables should be instantiated with either var/let, but there are multiple instances of such variables in a file. Now I can test whether the replaced variable is should be either var/let depending on its scope (var if its used in other functions as well or let if its used only within a block).
But for checking if its a global variable used across files, I will need to search it for individual variable flagged in the issue.
Is there some configuration in sonar thorugh which it will skip issues involving global variables or is there some tool/extension which has this capability?
I tried ES lint but could not find a proper rule to look for variable reference across multiple files.
